# About speed of divergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $X$ be the set of all monotonically increasing sequences of positive real numbers.

Let $f_n,\ g_n \in X$.

Define $f_n\sim g_n \equiv \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{g_n}{f_n}=c,\ c>0$.

And $f_n\ge g_n \equiv \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{g_n}{f_n}=0$.

Let $O(f_n)=\{ x_n| x_n \in X \land x_n \sim f_n\}$.

How do we construct the set $A=\{ O(f_n)|1 \le f_n \le n\}$?

Edit:

I actually mean that is it possible to construct $A$ from a set of known functions like $n^a, 2^n,log(n)$,ect. by finite multiplications and compositions.

i.e. Let $ B=\{n^a,2^n,log(n)|a \in \Bbb R\}$.

And a *word* of $B$ is a finite list of elements of $B$, in between each element of the list, there is a $\times,\circ $ and maybe a bracket. With appropriate contraction rules.
Does the set of all possible word of $B$ contains $A$? If not, how much stuff do we need to add into $B$?

And what would the cardinality of $A$ be?

Comment: Try to use the second definition given.

Comment: You wrote that $A$ is the set of classes $O(f_n)$ for all different $f_n$ subject to a given condition. That is a construction. $A$ has been constructed, right there. Can you be more specific about exactly what it is you want?